# javascript match specific name plus / and characters after it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

match a path for a specific word and a / and any characters that follow. 
For example.

```
const str = 'cars/ford';
const isCars = str.match('cars');
```

What I want to do is make sure it matches cars and has a slash and characters after the / then return true or false. 
The characters after cars/... will change so I can't match it excatly. Just need to match any characters along with the /

Comment: so use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and not a string match

Comment: I'd say regex is the way to go, but if for whatever reason you were avoiding that route, you could do something like `var strSplit = str.split("cars/"); 
return strSplit.length > 1 && !!strSplit[1];`

Comment: Would love to use regex not sure what it should be. Looking into how to achieve that via regex tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `test()` that returns **true** or **false**.

```js
const str = "cars/ford";

const str2 = "cars/";

var isCars = (str)=>/^cars\/./i.test(str)

console.log(isCars(str));
console.log(isCars(str2));
```

Comment: Great. What does .+/i do ?

Comment: @me-me `.` any character `+` one or more times,  and `i` is a flag for case sensitive

Comment: Thanks works great. If I wanted to match car and / and everything after it could I do that ? I know that wasn't the question but just for learning purposes .

Comment: @me-me yes something like `console.log(isCars("cars/Renault/SomeModel"))` returns true, any character except line breaks

Comment: Right I understand that. I guess the second question would be how to test for cars and everything after it. so if you typed. '/cars' it would match or if you types '/cars/ford'

Comment: You don't need `+`. A single `.` is enough.

Comment: You might need `+` if you were returning what's matched, but if you're just testing you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

> Would love to use regex not sure what it should be. Looking into how to achieve that via regex tutorials.

```js
var str = "cars/ford";
var patt = new RegExp("^cars/");       //or var patt = /^cars\//
var res = patt.test(str);              //true
console.log(res);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: I already picked an answer but thank you for the tut links super helpful.thanks you!!!

Comment: Just a note, OP mentioned *"make sure it matches cars and has a slash **and characters**"* - I believe the regex in your answer will return `true` for `cars/`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick regex to match "cars/" followed by any characters a-z.

```
(cars\/[a-z]+)
```

This will only match lowercase letters, so you can add the `i` flag to make it case insensitive.

```
/(cars\/[a-z]+)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic regular expression

```js
var str = "cars/ford"
var result = str.match(/^cars\/(.*)$/)
console.log(result)
```

```
^     - start
cars  - match exact characters
\/    - match /, the \ escapes it
(.*)  - capture group, match anything
$     - end of line
```

Visualize it: [RegExper](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Ecars%5C%2F%28.*%29%24%2F)